# What causes rashes to appear in specific parts of the body without a site specific trigger?

Tags: medicine

Why do rashes appear randomly at highly specific locations (and not others), without location specific triggers? Like, if it's a systemic issue, then it should be distributed to other areas on the body too.

Comment: It appeared on the back of my right hand, and nowhere else, and then died down. I've had similar rashes in the past where they appear without any obvious trigger, on a highly specific location and nowhere else, then disappear spontaneously after a few hours. 

I'm curious what, in theory, can possibly cause this observation. If I have sensitive skin, they should not be localized like this. 

I'm not asking for medical advice, just curious as to how exactly this even happens.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. In particular note that personal medical questions are **not** appropriate for this site. Saying it isn't personal is not enough when the text of your question contradicts you! This also seems likely to generate opinions rather than facts (also against site guidelines). Finally, we expect you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). Thanks! 

Comment: I've pared your question down a bit but it could still use some prior research to improve it. Keep the personal anecdotes out of it.